# File uploading with ActiveStorage in Vue.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, rails-activestorage

I'm looking to add file uploads to a Card model (including single and multiple files) using the new Rails 5.2 ActiveStorage feature. I'm stronger in Rails and am using Vue.js to pull this off - previously I would use Paperclip to handle this. However, I've setup the `config/storage.yml` file and necessary migrations for ActiveStorage. I've also set the association between on the Card and updated the `CardController` to permit `files: []`.

The `card.vue` component that I created currently works well; a Card can have a title and description, and the description can be updated. These records persist to the database. My problem is figuring out how to bind file uploads to the card, and the logic required to upload multiple files on save.

Currently I'm using `<input name="files" type="file" data-direct-upload-url="/rails/active_storage/direct_uploads" direct_upload="true" />` to create the input field in the card. However, after selecting a PDF image from my local machine and clicking save, the logs show that nothing happens [in regards to inserting a new row in active_storage_attachments or creating a blob]. How can I expand the save method to accept the file?

card.rb

```
class Card < ApplicationRecord
  has_many_attached :files
end
```

CardController

```
class CardsController < ApplicationController
  private
    def card_params
      params.require(:card).permit(:list_id, :title, :position, :description, files: [])
    end
end
```

card.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div @click="editing=true" class="card card-body">
      <h4>
        {{card.title}}
      </h4>
    </div>

    <div v-if="editing" class="modal-backdrop show"></div>

    <div v-if="editing" @click="closeModal" class="modal show" style="display: block">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <div>
              <h4>
                {{card.title}}
              </h4>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div>
              <h5>{{card.description}}</h5>
            </div>
            <textarea v-model="description" class="form-control"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <input name="files" type="file" data-direct-upload-url="/rails/active_storage/direct_uploads" direct_upload="true" />
            <button @click="save" type="button" class="button button-secondary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  props: ["card", "list"],

  data: function() {
    return {
      editing: false,
      title: this.card.title,
      description: this.card.description,
      files: []
    }
  },

  methods: {
    save: function() {
      var data = new FormData
      data.append("card[title]", this.title)
      data.append("card[description]", this.description)

      Rails.ajax({
        url: `/cards/${this.card.id}`,
        type: "PATCH",
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: (data) => {
          const list_index = window.store.lists.findIndex((item) => item.id == this.list.id)
          const card_index = window.store.lists[list_index].cards.findIndex((item) => item.id == this.card.id)
          window.store.lists[list_index].cards.splice(card_index, 1, data)

          this.editing = false
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 7):

Try to change your input name to fit with your permitted params:

```
<input name="card[files][]" type="file" ... />
```

---

**Updated**:

As I answered you need to change your params to fit with your permitted ones.
Now using Vue, you can remove the `name` and add the files to the FormData on change event like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    ...
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <input ref="files" type="file" @change="onFilesChange"
        data-direct-upload-url="/rails/active_storage/direct_uploads"
        direct_upload="true" multiple />
      <button @click="save" type="button" class="button button-secondary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
    ...   
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  props: ["card", "list"],

  data: function() {
    return {
      editing: false,
      title: this.card.title,
      description: this.card.description,
      form: new FormData
    }
  },

  methods: {
    onFilesChange: function() {
      let files = this.$refs.files.files
      for(let file of files) {
        this.form.append('card[files][]', file)
      }
    },
    save: function() {
      this.form.append("card[title]", this.title)
      this.form.append("card[description]", this.description)

      Rails.ajax({
        url: `/cards/${this.card.id}`,
        type: "PATCH",
        data: this.form,
        dataType: "json",
        success: (data) => {
          // ...
          this.editing = false
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Note: don't forget the `multiple` property on input if you want to upload multiple files.

Comment: Okay let me give that a try, you think that is sufficient to bind the file?

Comment: The logs back after updating the input field and trying to attach a file doesn't show anything pertaining to the blob being created. Still a little stuck on how to bind the file

Comment: Hey @Sovalina this updated snippet works great. It inserts the file into ActiveStorage::Blob and ActiveStorage::Attachment, and through my association makes the record_id of the Attachment the id of the Card.

I'm going to try to display this file for preview now.

Comment: Do you have any tips?

Comment: @VegaStudios, glad to hear that it works. About tips, you mean how to preview the files before the upload ?

Comment: Yeah exactly, the references in the doc use image_url and translating that to work in Vue didn't work at first. Do I need to use bind or anything? Simply looking to display the file for download in the modal (separate from the input button)

Comment: I've got the direct uploading working fine, and the attachments persist to S3. Do you know @sovalina how I could display a link to the `card[files][]` in the `<template>` view?

Answer (score 0):

I tend to do it this way:

```
let input_file = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="file"]')

// ...

formData.append('card[files]', input_file.files[0]) // or loop through if need be, also it might be card[files][0], I can't remember
```

Not sure if you need many files or just one. And this is provided you don't want to submit it in an async way like your code seems to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full solution using Rails with Active Storage, Direct Upload, and Vue JS. Upon dropping files, they 1) upload to storage solution via Direct Upload (provided by Rails), 2) immediately create form for rails model to add attachment. I really struggled learning various things and had some challenges with vue updating the dom, but ultimately I did workarounds and arrived at the following. A lot of solutions were sparse online and some used some weird practices. This does not have any progress indicators aside from indeterminate spinners. One general idea I learned throughout this is that Active Storage first must upload the file to the storage device, saving a record in the database, but it must subsequently also attach that uploaded file to a rails model and save it.

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import { DirectUpload } from "@rails/activestorage"

export default {
    props: {
        modelName: String,
        modelNamePlural: String,
        modelId: Number,
        directUploadsUrl: String,
        authenticityToken: String
    },
    data: () => ({ 
        files: [],
        uploadedFiles: [],
        hovered: false
    }),
    methods: {
      fileDropped(e) {
        console.log('File(s) dropped: ');
        console.log(e.dataTransfer.files);
        console.log('----------------------');
        this.hovered = false;
        let that = this;
        Array.from(e.dataTransfer.files).forEach(function (file, index) {
            file.isUploading = true;
            that.files.push(file);
            that.uploadFile(file, index);
        });
      },
      uploadFile(file, index) {
        const upload = new DirectUpload(file, this.directUploadsUrl);
        setTimeout(() => {
            upload.create((error, blob) => {
                if (error) {

                } else {
                    let formData = new FormData();
                    formData.append(this.modelName.toLowerCase() + "[bols][]", blob.signed_id);
                    const options = { headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}};
                    const url = "/" + this.modelNamePlural + "/" + this.modelId;
                    axios.put(url, formData, options).then((res) => {
                        this.files.splice(index,1);
                        this.uploadedFiles.push(file);
                    });
                }
            });

        }, 2000);
      }
  }
}
</script>


<template>
    <div id="file-uploader">
        <div class="file-uploader__drop-zone p-3" :class="{ hovered: hovered }" @dragover.prevent @drop.prevent="fileDropped" @dragenter="hovered=true" @dragleave="hovered=false">
            <span class="file-uploader__drop-zone-text">
                <span class="fa fa-file-o"></span>
                Drop Files
            </span>
            <div v-if="files.length" class="file-uploader__file-list">
                <div v-for="file in files" :key="file.name">
                    <span>{{file.name}}</span>
                    <span>Uploading? {{file.isUploading || false}}</span>
                    <span>Success? {{file.uploadedSuccessfully || false}}</span>
                    <span class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin" v-show="file.isUploading"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div v-for="file in uploadedFiles" :key="file.name">
            {{file.name}} <span class="fa fa-check text-success"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<style>
    #file-uploader .file-uploader__file-list {
        pointer-events: none;
    }
    #file-uploader .file-uploader__drop-zone {
        background-color: #eee;
        border: 2px solid #ddd;
        border-radius: 3px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #file-uploader .file-uploader__drop-zone.hovered {
        border: 2px solid #03e7ff;
    }
    #file-uploader .file-uploader__drop-zone-text {
        color: #999;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
</style>
```